# Fail to execute goal : tycho-p2-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-jdt, tycho

When trying to create a headless rcp eclipse version using tycho with the following pom.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-

8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>eclipse-mars</id>
         <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest</url>
         <layout>p2</layout>
      </repository>
   </repositories>

   <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>     
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <strictVersions>false</strictVersions>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration />
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
         <version>3.7.1</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

I get the folllowing error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.4.0:p2-metadata-default (default-p2-metadata-default) on project test2: Execution default-p2-metadata-default of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-plugin:1.4.0:p2-metadata-default failed. IllegalArgumentException
```

Which arguments does this IllegalArgumentException refer to? 
Is this a bug or a result from the pom.xml itself or rather an issue from other files (I don't want to include the whole project here so feel free to ask for files)

Answer (score 0):

Run the buıild with -X flag. like `mvn clean verify -X`. In my case it was a typo in version.

Wrote 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT instead  1.0.0-SNAPSHOT